# What does mean the bolded words

Tags: meaning

One amplifier would be concerned with the bass and another amplifier would be concerned with volume, and another one ....or we could have a mixer, or we could have lots of mixers and what we all be playing **John is what it would amount to**

I don't understand what does mean the bolded words

how can they be playing John (John Cale), John is a musician, a man

extracts from uptight (the Velvet Underground story) Lou Reed is speaking about ideas he has to create music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the whole paragraph explains that the viola, John's instrument, had multiple contact microphones attached to it and connected to a mixer, which was routed to the other musicians who would manipulate the sound produced. So, in a sense, they were "playing him".
The language in that book seems to be a transcription of speech, and it is not punctuated very well. It should say "... what we would all be playing is, "John" is what it would amount to."
Here:[a link to the paragraph on Google books](https://tinyurl.com/uamy2tx)

Comment: what I still don't understand is what it would amount to (is this refering to John or the other )

Comment: John is playing his viola. His sound is electrically transmitted to the other musicians. The other musicians manipulate that sound electrically. Their contribution to the band's sound is that modified version of John's sound. Thus, they are metaphorically "playing John". Does that help?

Comment: Just about the phrase "what it would amount to", they are saying that their playing "would amount to", or "would be the same as", John's sound.

Answer (score 0):

“...playing «person’s name»” is a commonly-used verbal shorthand for “...playing music by ...” - that is, “The orchestra is playing Bach” would be understood as “The orchestra is playing music by [Johann Sebastian] Bach”. It could be referring to the author, as in my example; it could also be referring to the performer, if the performer is ‘covering’ somebody else’s work. (As an example, the quartet that performs under the name **bond** has their own arrangement of *The 1812 Overture* by Tchaikovski. If I were listening to **bond**’s arrangement, and I wanted to so indicate, I might say that “I’m listening to **bond**”, even though the piece was authored by Tchaikovski.)